# Buttons disapper on adding new list items?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a list using javascript.After every list item, there are two buttons inserted. But these buttons appear only on last list item.Please help me.
[My Code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRrJLQ)

Here is my function which updates the list using JS`

```
function updateView() {
    fetchFromLocal(); //fetches list from local storage and updates TaskList array
    list.innerHTML = ""; //list is var that points to unordered list

    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
    var btnUp = document.createElement("input");
    btnUp.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btnUp.setAttribute('value', '^');
    // console.log(btnUp);
    var btnDown = document.createElement("input");
    btnDown.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btnDown.setAttribute('value', 'v');


    for(var i=0;i<TaskList.length;i++)
    {
        var TempElem = document.createElement("li");
        //console.log(TempElem);

        TempElem.appendChild(checkbox);
        // console.log("Elem after checkbox " + TempElem.innerHTML);
        TempElem.innerHTML += " <span class='listitem'> " + TaskList[i] + "</span>";
        // console.log("Elem after tasklist "+ TempElem.innerHTML);
        TempElem.appendChild(btnUp);
        TempElem.appendChild(btnDown);
        console.log("Final Tepelem " + TempElem.innerHTML);
        list.appendChild(TempElem);

    }
}
```

Comment: Saying 'please don't downvote' is not a valid reason not to downvote. State what your problem is, like you did, add your code - like you did and that's it.

Comment: Then why did you downvote? I really want to ask some questions here and you just downvoted me again :(

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are appending the same element so since the same element can not be in more than one place it is moved to the new location. You need to clone them before appending.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

```
TempElem.appendChild(checkbox.cloneNode(true));
```

You need to do it to the buttons also.

Comment: so I guss using "let" instead of "var" should resolve the issue. let would be block scoped and it shouldn't cause a problem right ?

Comment: Okay, I finally got your point sir. I moved the checkbox,btnUp and btnDown initialisation inside for loop.That solved it, thanks !

Comment: cloning it would have been just as easy, but moving it inside is fine also.

Comment: But I need a little clarification, why were all the checkboxes still apperaing , although var checkbox = document.createElement("input"); was outside loop

Comment: because you used innerHTML to add the span. So you basically made a new element when you replaced the innerHTML. FYI: you really should be using a label and not a span. When you replace the innerHTML, you kill the reference since when you add it back it is a new element, bad thing about it is if you added an event listener to the input, you would remove that.